# Visual Studio 2015 (C++) code size

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015

Importing my projects from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015 and compiling them makes DLL size jump from about 80kb to 380kb. (I mainly compile C / C++ DLL's)

I have tried playing with the linker settings but no luck in getting the size down again, including the new incremental linking.

Does anyone know what causes this and how to get it down again ?

Comment: Debug information? Try to use strip (-s) parameter usually.

Comment: ^^^ If you turn on everything, bounds-checking, full remote-debug symbols etc, I bet you can bloat it up even more;)

Comment: What are "C / C++ DLL's"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit they would be the ones that just shut down the app without even an error messagebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was this one here: /OPT:REF

(Victors -s tip put me on that track, thanks)

I don't know why this gets messed up when upgrading to 2015.